# Passing non const variables to a function with const arguments in C

Tags: c

I have a function as below

```
void foo(const foo_type* x)
{...}
```

I am calling this function in other function.

```
void foo1(int z)
{
    foo_type y = z;
    foo(&y);
}
```

This is not throwing any error in c but i feel something is not correct.
What happens when i pass non const variable to function that expects const variable as arguments.

Comment: The function considers the pointed object as a constant object and nothing more.

Comment: this is perfectly ok. The other way around would be a problem (const to mutable cast)

Answer (score 7):

The *introduction* of `const` in the way you have is absolutely fine *and* even desirable.

You have told the compiler explicitly that the function will not modify the parameter passed as `const`. That could even help with a compiler's optimisation strategy.

The *removal* of `const` is, in general, a bad idea though. (Which you're not doing in this case.) The behaviour on modifying a variable via the removal of `const` that was originally declared as `const` is *undefined*.